# Pointer of slice of pointers panicking when making

Tags: pointers, go, slice

I have the following code :

```
var ANIMATIONS *[]*SDL.Animable

....

func main() {
    *ANIMATIONS = make([]*SDL.Animable, 0, 100)
```

But its panicking when running. What is the right way of initializing this?

Error :

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x8 pc=0x4afe3a]

goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
main.main()
```

Comment: Further to the answer given, it's very rare to need a pointer to a slice; it's even more rare to create one (vs passing one). Re-visit why you think your variable should be a pointer. Also, all-caps identifier names are not idiomatic Go.

Comment: @DaveC thanks for your comment Dave. Thing is I need to pass this slice to a function, which in turn will pass it to another function and the latter will add a few animations to it. When I attempted to use append without it being a pointer the changes would not reflect as were passed by copy.

Comment: @DaveC if you can show me an example of how to append to a passed slice without needing a pointer it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If "need to pass this slice to a function" then I'd take your `var foo []*Thing` and pass it as `someFunctionWantingASlicePointer(&foo)`. Notice I made a distinction between "creating one" and "passing one" in my comment.

Comment: @DaveC Thanks. I'll try this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix, you want:

```
s := make([]*SDL.Animable, 0, 100)

ANIMATIONS = &s
```

The reason your code was panicking is basically you were dereferencing a nil pointer (`*ANIMATIONS`). You need to get a reference variable to store your new slice & then you can get it's address (`&s`) and store that in your pointer.

*Note:* the following will *NOT* work `&make([]*SDL.Animable, 0, 100)` - as you cannot get the address of a returned result - hence the need to store the result & get it's address.